# Node JS AWS SQS only receiving one message

Tags: node.js, amazon-sqs

I have 3 messages at my aws message inbox. But i am only getting one message when I'm trying
to retrieve all. I am getting only the last message, but the other two messages are not showing.
Here is my code:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "REGION" });

const sqs = new AWS.SQS({ apiVersion: "2012-11-05" });

const readMessage = function () {
  const params = {
    MaxNumberOfMessages: 10,
    QueueUrl: "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/56622448/my-queue",
  };

  sqs.receiveMessage(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    } else if (data.Messages) {
       console.log(data);
    }
  });
};

readMessage();
```

This is the output:

```
{
  ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: 'a9e53cee-afc8-57c-664408f1e602' },
  Messages: [
    {
      MessageId: 'bb3e23f9-07fd-4205-9b53-a48f826',
      ReceiptHandle: 'AQEBD6rCOZlaBfCNn3nU4AEE7OlYwFJFeblTaiDoxIy8HiwsjdxZX+3SICY/YW5PI+RuFscMMh6VyExoo1i8Zo2JlbYj3t32b9CXnToYugzBqgZuxuYOTzXRAnrGwlavSL7hcLQvW6y8me1gnj65N3tPYEmcfXX5GIiQTn1yNEou3rUNff9DfkSije/0zvp33yfWfcW+RDzB2y6ND6eKHxfsP/cqmHjRaT0bE9rlXorjgh36YwVJ57e5bjUa/1dVqOf3ybXfEX/5C2eZM+T1V2JBxlguvuL1B3aHKAC+R9Pdgpdg2kmK3+bVmOxbQJKfU0s3sD9fElZJmLuLLMPb835z5hbVv44fKJVuEc7ad2uL3d1AUCbq3MKRCb38t77L4Ifa/ob3QQ==',
      MD5OfBody: '7b84813a4b4bf10f0edb9e8da7',
      Body: "Handsome Person Basic Information."
    }
  ]
}
```

My Expected Output:

```
{
      ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: 'a9e53cee-afc8-57c-664408f1e602' },
      Messages: [
        {
          MessageId: 'bb3e23f9-07fd-4205-9b53-a48f826',
          ReceiptHandle: 'AQEBD6rCOZlaBfCNn3nU4AEE7OlYwFJFeblTaiDoxIy8HiwsjdxZX+3SICY/YW5PI+RuFscMMh6VyExoo1i8Zo2JlbYj3t32b9CXnToYugzBqgZuxuYOTzXRAnrGwlavSL7hcLQvW6y8me1gnj65N3tPYEmcfXX5GIiQTn1yNEou3rUNff9DfkSije/0zvp33yfWfcW+RDzB2y6ND6eKHxfsP/cqmHjRaT0bE9rlXorjgh36YwVJ57e5bjUa/1dVqOf3ybXfEX/5C2eZM+T1V2JBxlguvuL1B3aHKAC+R9Pdgpdg2kmK3+bVmOxbQJKfU0s3sD9fElZJmLuLLMPb835z5hbVv44fKJVuEc7ad2uL3d1AUCbq3MKRCb38t77L4Ifa/ob3QQ==',
          MD5OfBody: '7b84813a4b4bf10f0edb9e8da7',
          Body: "Handsome Person Basic Information."
        },
       {
        Body: "Handsome Person Basic Information II"
       },
       {
        Body: "Handsome Person Basic Information III"
       }
      ]
    }
```

Under messages, i should be getting three. but retrieving is only one message.

Take note: I have just short cut the value of my expected value just to prove my point.

How would I able to get all of the three messages? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of AWS SQS

"If the number of messages in the queue is small (fewer than 1,000), you most likely get fewer messages than you requested per ReceiveMessage call. If the number of messages in the queue is extremely small, you might not receive any messages in a particular ReceiveMessage response. If this happens, repeat the request. "

[Class ReceiveMessageCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-sqs/classes/receivemessagecommand.html)

Long polling might help, but not guarantee you will receive all message at once

Answer (score -1):

Long polling is the solution. You can achieve by 2 ways :

1. Recall your "readMessage()" recursively(I won't recommend to use setInterval)
2. Use npm [SQS-consumer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqs-consumer)